# PySpark: How to update row if new value exists?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame in pyspark following below:

| id | Datetime | price | amountOld | amountNew |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210203 | 200 | 20 | 30 |
| 1 | 20210204 | 230 | None | None |
| 1 | 20210205 | 225 | None | None |
| 1 | 20210206 | 233 | 30 | 50 |
| 1 | 20210207 | 220 | None | None |
| 2 | 20210407 | 400 | None | None |
| 2 | 20210408 | 410 | 90 | 100 |
| 2 | 20210409 | 415 | None | None |
| 2 | 20210410 | 423 | None | None |

I want to add a column to that like below:

| id | Datetime | price | amountOld | amountNew | currentAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210203 | 200 | 20 | 30 | 30 |
| 1 | 20210204 | 230 | None | None | 30 |
| 1 | 20210205 | 225 | None | None | 30 |
| 1 | 20210206 | 233 | 30 | 50 | 50 |
| 1 | 20210207 | 220 | None | None | 50 |
| 2 | 20210407 | 400 | None | None | 90 |
| 2 | 20210408 | 410 | 90 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 20210409 | 415 | None | None | 100 |
| 2 | 20210410 | 423 | None | None | 100 |

I have tried many times like the code below but no luck:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(df_final.Datetime.desc())

df_final = df_final. \
    withColumn("currentAmount",
               when(col("amountNew").isNotNull(), 
               lag(col("amountNew")).over(w)) \
               .otherwise(lag(col("amountOld")).over(w)))
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: what's the result you get?

Comment: @Christophe Result is that lag function works one time and shift the column amountNew to the new row. It is not the excepted result that I want.

Comment: In `otherwise` clause, shouldn't you put `currentAmount` instead of `amountOld`?

Comment: @Christophe There is no access to the previous value when you use withColumn and it throws 'cannot resolve '`currentAmount`' given input columns'.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it was too obvious! Anyway, `lag(col("amountNew"))` will return `None` in your case. I'll try to find a solution, but you could look for something with a kind of a cte (intermediate dataframe created with relevant filter, for instance latest not null row) then use it in a left join according to conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `first`,`last` from `functions` over `window`

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('Datetime').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.currentRow)
w2 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('Datetime').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow,Window.unboundedFollowing)

df_final = df_final.withColumn('currentAmount',f.coalesce(f.last('amountNew',ignorenulls=True).over(w1),f.first('amountOld',ignorenulls=True).over(w2)))

dff.show()
+---+--------+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
| id|Datetime|price|amountOld|amountNew|currentAmount|
+---+--------+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
|  1|20210203|  200|       20|       30|           30|
|  1|20210204|  230|     null|     null|           30|
|  1|20210205|  225|     null|     null|           30|
|  1|20210206|  233|       30|       50|           50|
|  1|20210207|  220|     null|     null|           50|
|  2|20210407|  400|     null|     null|           90|
|  2|20210408|  410|       90|      100|          100|
|  2|20210409|  415|     null|     null|          100|
|  2|20210410|  423|     null|     null|          100|
+---+--------+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm.